# Is there a way to remove function arguments if they have NULL in them

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a function that takes any number of arguments and filters a dataframe based on those arguments - basically in the same way that dplyr does this. In some cases though these arguments can become NULL (because this is a function used in shiny). Is there a way to remove these arguments? I've provided example code showing what I mean below.

```
cylFilter <- 6
mpgFilter <- 21
dispFilter <- NULL
newFilter <- function(df, ...){
  dots <- dplyr::enquos(...)
  quo <- dplyr:::all_exprs(!!!dots, .vectorised = TRUE)
  df <- dplyr:::filter_impl(df, quo)
  return(df)
}
newFilter(mtcars, cyl == cylFilter, mpg == mpgFilter, disp == dispFilter)
```

Desired output:

```
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: In order to determine is something is NULL you have to evaluate it and when you use `enquo` you are explicitly not evaluating parameters so you've got an evaluation problem here. If you want to dynamically build a filter, it would probably better to dynamically built a list of criteria rather than filtering function parameters after the call. What exactly are the requirements for `newFilter`? If you are only using this as a shiny backend, do you really need to use non-standard evaluation?

Comment: newFilter is a simplification, but the issue is that I have hundreds of different columns so it isn't possible to make a custom filter function that details each of the possible options as a normal argument.

Comment: It would be better if the function took a list of (possibly-null) values for each of the columns, and then you can filter that list before expanding into function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible answers depending on how consistent your filtering expressions are:

1. If your expressions are always of the form A == B of A == NULL:

   In this case, you can selectively evaluate part of the captured expression, check if it's NULL, and remove it from the list of captured arguments

   ```r
   newFilter_opt1 <- function(df, ...) {
       dots <- dplyr::enquos(...)
       dots2 <- dplyr::enexprs(...)
       #Below could be replaced with purrr::map_logical(dots, check_not_null)
       is_ok <- vapply(dots2, check_not_null, logical(1))  
       dots <- dots[is_ok]
       quo <- dplyr:::all_exprs(!!!dots, .vectorised = TRUE)
       df <- dplyr:::filter_impl(df, quo)
       return(df)
   }

   check_not_null <- function(expr) {
       # In R, the expression A == B is turned into [`==`, A, B]
       # We need to check if the third part of this expression evaluates to NULL
       return(!is.null(eval(expr[[3]])))
   }
   ```
2. If you don't know what form your expressions come in:

   Now it's much harder to check before hand if the captured expressions contain NULL. 
   Instead, run each expression through dplyr::filter individually, and catch any errors

   ```r
   newFilter_opt2 <- function(df, ...) {
       dots <- dplyr::enquos(...)
       for (x in dots) {
           df <- filter_or_catch(df, x)
       }
       return(df)
   }

   filter_or_catch <- function(df, x) {
       res <- tryCatch(
           {
               dplyr::filter(df, !!x)
           },
           error = function(e) df
       )
       return(res)
   }
   ```

For the example, both approaches give the desired output:

```r
cylFilter <- 6
mpgFilter <- 21
dispFilter <- NULL
newFilter_opt1(mtcars, cyl == cylFilter, mpg == mpgFilter, disp == dispFilter)
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

newFilter_opt2(mtcars, cyl == cylFilter, mpg == mpgFilter, disp == dispFilter)
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

For small datasets, newFilter_opt1 is signficantly faster:

```r
timing <- bench::mark(newFilter_opt1(mtcars, cyl == cylFilter, mpg == mpgFilter, disp == dispFilter),
                      newFilter_opt2(mtcars, cyl == cylFilter, mpg == mpgFilter, disp == dispFilter))
timing[, 1] <- c("opt1", "opt2")
timing[, c(1:8)]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 opt1        315.6us  358.6us     2223.    44.5KB    10.4 
#> 2 opt2         1.77ms    2.3ms      273.    3.28KB     5.11
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Paul, I have one further question to follow this one up and was wondering if you can help? I want to make a wrapper for this function to run for particular use cases, but I found that this causes a problem with your check_not_null solution because objects are not evaluated. I'll explain in more detail in an edit to the question